# Unable to read messagepack bytes into Uint8Array buffer in js

Tags: javascript, python, msgpack

I've spend the last hour trying to do a simple hello world with messagepack between Python and Javascript (well, ClojureScript ...). For some reason I can't read the msgpack payload into a javascript buffer correctly.

I'm using `msgpack-python` and `msgpack-lite`.

## Python

In Python I'm generating my payload and writing to a binary file as follows:

```
bts = msgpack.packb({"blah": 1, "bleh": [0, 1]}, default=encode)
with open('/tmp/sample.msgpack', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bts)
```

This message appears to be correct, since I can verify its hexdump in https://kawanet.github.io/msgpack-lite/, though I do need to add spaces in the generated string ... I used the following line to generate the hex representation:

```
codecs.getencoder('hex_codec')(bts)[0]`)
# b'82a4626c6568920001a4626c616801'
```

## Javascript

I'm serving this binary file using `http-server -p 3000 --cors`. The response body of a simple GET in Javascript land is as follows: `��bleh���blah`. My problem is that I can't load it into a Uint8Array correctly:

```
Uint8Array.from(body)
// Uint8Array(15) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
new Uint8Array(body) 
// Uint8Array(0)
```

What am I doing wrong? Clearly the payload is not all zeros as we can see in the messy byte representation. I'm also quite surprised that using `.from()` generates an array of the correct length but then fails to set the content.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you receive a blop, I had similar problem and solved it by using FileReader and read it as buffer string.

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsBinaryString(body)
reader.onload = function(e) {
    const data = e.target.result
    var buffer = new Uint8Array(data.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = data.cahrCodeAt(i)
    }
    const decoded = msgpack.decode(buffer)
    console.log(decoded) // <-- Your unpacked message
}
```